# Does reloading of app in Reactjs while changing pages removes all the saved states

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Does Reloading of react app i.e not implementing  will remove all the saved state in our react app

Edit:
To be more specific ,
The question was what will happen to the child components state when its parent component gets reloaded i.e whether the state will be removed or not

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague, but it depends:

If you are reloading your entire react app then yes, all your states will be lost. You can however persist data using localStorage in most cases.

If you are reloading a component from your app, you can save state using useEffect, or by using react class components rather than functional components and use the componenetDidUpdate function to catch updates. Additionally componentDidMount can help you recognise when a component is re-rendered and use it to read persisted data from localStorage

If your component is within another component that does reload then yes it will also reload and state will be lost.

You can read more about the component life-cycle in the [react-docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) but they don't really touch on it.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, It cleared my doubt as I was looking for the 3rd point that you answered i.e whether what will happen if a component is declared within another component and its parent component gets reloaded.